# how can i use an input from html form in my javascript function?

Tags: javascript

Am new to js and would like to use values from an input in my js 'if' code. I wrote the code below but it does not render. Can you tell me what i did wrong.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var age = document.getElementById('selection').value;
   if (age < 4) {
    alert('The child is too young');
    } else if (age > 40) {
        alert('You are too old for this course');
    }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit=" myFunction()">
    Age: <input type="text" id="selection" name="age">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: There is typo here `var age =(document`. Please remove the extra opening brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are very close.

this one should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>js loops</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="loops.css">
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var age = document.getElementById('selection').value;
        if (age < 4) {
          alert('The child is too young');
        } else if (age > 40) {
          alert('You are too old for this course');
        }
        return false;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
      Age: <input type="text" id="selection" name="age">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```